# views exposed filter on non existent field

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type which has the following fields:

- month: List (integer) [jan, feb, ..., dec] (non mandatory)
- year: Date (only collects year - mandatory)

I can normally create two exposed views filters, one for the month and one for the year.

What I'd like to do though is have a single exposed filter which, internally, would operate on the two fields above at once.

For example if the operator is "Is Between" and the user selects `Oct 2011` to `Feb 2012` I'd like the filter to return only nodes which have:

- 2011, Oct
- 2011, Nov
- 2011, Dec
- 2012, NULL month
- 2012, Jan
- 2012, Feb

Note that I've used two fields (month and year) instead of one so I can have the possibility of a monthless node.

What approach should I take? I've thought of the following:

- use a third field which, on `hook_node_presave` will store the calculated (filter specific) date on the node. I wouldn't like this field to be visible on the edit node screen though
- somehow (using a hook) calculate and rewrite the view filtering query. My problem here is how to display an exposed filter for a field which does not exist

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution to me would be to get the month data into the date field, since you are treating the date to be 1/1 when no month is given, this would fit just fine; there is no reason to create a new field for this.

You should be able to do this in a form submission handler for the node edit form.

Comment: The reason why I need two fields is to have the ability for a `NULL` month. Then the presentation should display "2012" instead of "2012 Jan". On sorting and filtering though I'd treat `NULL` as `Jan`.

Comment: @cherouvim You don't understand - since you only display the year in the date field, you can still store  month and year.

Comment: Are you sure that this is possible? Can a date field which only collects a year store a month and a day? I tried within a `hook_node_presave` to do `$node->field_year['und'][0]['value'] = "2019-02-03 00:00:00";` and when I got it back the date was `2019-01-01 00:00:00` which means that the month and day values where lost.

Comment: Do you confirm that what you propose is doable? Because I don't.

Comment: @cherouvim I can confirm that it works, something is wrong with your code.